# Thumbnail generating and posting

Tags: thumbnails, cropping

I have PHP code that generates a thumbnail, but it crops out the wrong part of the image and displays wrong. How does it know what part to crop out, and how do I fix that to crop out the portion of the image I want? Here is the code:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail( 'profile-thumb' );
}
// Check if post thumbnail exists
else {
    $values = CFS()->get( 'gender' );   
    if ( is_array( $values ) ) {
        foreach ( $values as $value => $label ) {
            //echo '<h1 style="color:red">' . $value . '</h1>';
            echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/img/thumb-' . 
                $value . '.png"' . 'alt="thumbnail" />';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How image gets cropped depends on how the respective size was defined with [`add_image_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size).

In the past it was limited to soft or hard crop modes, always respective to the center of image. Now you can also pass more elaborate directions for the crop, such as `array( 'left', 'top' )`. See the linked documentation for details.

Note that the size applies to *all* images in general. If you want control over cropping of individual thumbnail, image editor in admin allows that to some degree (Edit image > Apply changes to > thumbnail).

Comment: I tried cropping the image in the media editor and there it looks fine. How do I link to that thumbnail?

Comment: You'll have to use the respective size. It's `post-thumbnail` or something like that on top of my head.